# Having issues with validation of input field

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate an input field. When i try to submit without filling in something, it gives me the error i made: please start your question with: will i ever. So i'm trying to check wether the text that the user types into the field, starts with: will i ever.

However, when i type a single (or more) random character(s), it just submits the form. I want it to check if the input starts with those fixed tree words, otherwise, no submission.

```js
{
  const handleSubmitForm = e => {
  const $form = e.currentTarget;
  if (!$form.checkValidity()) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const field = $form.querySelector('.question_field');
    showValidationInfo(field);

    //$form.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = 'Some errors occured';
  } else {
    console.log('Form is valid => submit form');
  }
};

const showValidationInfo = field => {
  console.log(field);
  let message;
  if (field.validity.valueMissing) {
    message = 'Please fill in a question starting with: Will i ever';
  }
  if (field.validity.typeMismatch) {
    message = 'Type not right';
  }
  if (field.validity.rangeOverflow) {
    const max = field.getAttribute('max');
    message = 'Too big, max ${max}';
  }
  if (field.validity.rangeUnderflow) {
    const min = field.getAttribute('min');
    message = 'Too small, min ${min}';
  }
  if (field.validity.tooShort) {
    const min = field.getAttribute('minlength');
    message = 'Too short, minimum length is ${min}';
  }
  if (field.validity.tooLong) {
    const max = field.getAttribute('maxlength');
    message = 'Too long, maximum length is ${max}';
  }
  if (!field.value.toLowerCase().startsWith("will i ever")) {
    message = 'Start your question with: Will i ever';
  }
  if (message) {
    field.parentElement.querySelector('.error').textContent = 
   message;
    field.parentElement.querySelector('.error').style.color = "red";
  }
};

const handeInputField = e => {
  const $field = e.currentTarget;
  if ($field.checkValidity()) {
    $field.parentElement.querySelector('.error').textContent = '';
    if ($field.form.checkValidity()) {
      $field.form.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = '';
    }
  }
};

const handeBlurField = e => {
  const $field = e.currentTarget;
  showValidationInfo($field);
};

const addValidationListeners = fields => {
  fields.forEach($field => {
    $field.addEventListener('input', handeInputField);
    $field.addEventListener('blur', handeBlurField);
  });
};

const init = () => {
  const $form = document.querySelector('form');
  $form.noValidate = true;
  $form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmitForm);

  const fields = $form.querySelectorAll('.input');
  addValidationListeners(fields);
};

init();
}
```

```html
<div class="name_wrapper">
  <form autocomplete="off" class="form_question" action="answer.html">
    <label class="name question" for="name">Ask me a question</label>
    <div class="question_wrapper">
      <p class="error">Start your question with: Will i ever...</p>
      <input class="field question_field" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Will i ever..." value="" required>
    </div>
    <input id="button" class="answr-btn btn-question" type="submit" value="answer it!">
    <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML too?

Comment: After getting the value of the input you then can `"will i ever" !== value.slice(0, 11)`

Comment: first of all, I think your quotation marks are placed wrong. The code example shows red text where it thinks it's a string, but you write an if statement.

Comment: "text" or 'text' is better than \`text\`.  Because the ` mark is used a lot in MySQL or here as a `code` markup.

Comment: the problem begins at: `//$form.querySelector(`.error`).innerHTML = \`Some errors 
 occurred\`;`

Comment: i edited in the HTML.

Comment: 2x2p - that line of code is just a comment, or are you saying it's because of my else statement below that line?

Comment: If the question *has* to start with, and therefore all valid questions *will* start with, 'will I ever' (incidentally 'will' should be capitalised, in the English language at least) why are you forcing your users to type that, instead of auto-populating the text field or prepending that string to the resulting value?

Comment: Hi David, i have set up a js.file for the next page that loads after submission. If my input value doesn't start with will i ever, the result on my page will just not be correct. So for me it would just be the best solution that they have to start their sentence with those 3 words. And by the way, it's only a small project for my school, not for commercial use or anything like that.

Comment: But since your brought up auto-populating the text field, how would i do that? And is it possible in that case the form will not submit if the sentence doesn't start with the words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are handling the validation, the key is in this line `if (!$form.checkValidity()) {` this will not check if your string starts with `Will i ever` you have to do it manually before the if, here you have an alternative solution:

```js
{
 const handleSubmitForm = e => {
  
  const $form = e.currentTarget;
  const field = $form.querySelector('.question_field');
  //here we validate the form manually
  const message = showValidationInfo(field);
  //if a message is found we show the error on the DOM, if is undefined we have no errors and we can submit the form
  if (message) {
    e.preventDefault();

  $form.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = message;
  $form.querySelector('.error').style.color = "red";
} else {
  console.log('Form is valid => submit form');
}
 };

const showValidationInfo = field => {
  if (field.validity.valueMissing) {
    return 'Please fill in a question starting with: Will i ever';
  }
  if (field.validity.typeMismatch) {
    return 'Type not right';
  }
  if (field.validity.rangeOverflow) {
    const max = field.getAttribute('max');
    return 'Too big, max ${max}';
  }
  if (field.validity.rangeUnderflow) {
    const min = field.getAttribute('min');
    return 'Too small, min ${min}';
  }
  if (field.validity.tooShort) {
    const min = field.getAttribute('minlength');
    return 'Too short, minimum length is ${min}';
  }
  if (field.validity.tooLong) {
    const max = field.getAttribute('maxlength');
    return 'Too long, maximum length is ${max}';
  }
  if (!field.value.toLowerCase().startsWith("will i ever")) {
    return 'Start your question with: Will i ever';
  }

  return undefined;
};

const handeInputField = e => {
const $field = e.currentTarget;
if ($field.checkValidity()) {
  $field.parentElement.querySelector('.error').textContent = '';
  if ($field.form.checkValidity()) {
    $field.form.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
};

const handeBlurField = e => {
const $field = e.currentTarget;
showValidationInfo($field);
};

const addValidationListeners = fields => {
fields.forEach($field => {
  $field.addEventListener('input', handeInputField);
  $field.addEventListener('blur', handeBlurField);
});
};

const init = () => {
const $form = document.querySelector('form');
$form.noValidate = true;
$form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmitForm);

const fields = $form.querySelectorAll('.input');
addValidationListeners(fields);
};

init();
}
```

```html
<div class="name_wrapper">
        <form autocomplete="off" class="form_question" action="answer.html">
            <label class="name question" for="name">Ask me a question</label>
            <div class="question_wrapper">
            <p class="error">Start your question with: Will i ever...</p>
                <input class="field question_field" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Will i ever..." value="" required>
            </div>
            <input id="button" class="answr-btn btn-question" type="submit" value="answer it!">
            <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This line makes no sense:

```
const fields = $form.querySelectorAll('.input');
```

There are no HTML elements with `class="input"` in your form.

Did you mean `$form.querySelectorAll('input')`?

Comment: thanks for that notice, the original validation was for multiple input fields, i only use 1 input field here. Forgot to change that.

Comment: @ArthurRobaeys Huh? The issue is with class selectors (`.input`) vs. tag selectors (`input`), not multiple fields.

Comment: Yes, indeed. In this case i should've changed it to .querySelector('.question_field'). The line you selected was a line i forgot to edit.

Comment: I edited the line, and now right before i click submit with a value that's totally random, the error message quickly shows up before submitting the form anyway. So it seems the if statement for the input starting with:'Will i ever' works, but it submits anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You have uncommented backtick at `occured`   `;